# Strange variables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

Can someone tell me what "skip_name_resolve" and "skip_grant_tables" MySQL variables do ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. To get the most out of this site, I suggest you read the [Help Center on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Your question is understandable, but it doesn't have any specific code problem. This question is better suited to one of the sister sites, e.g. dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables

> --skip-grant-tables causes the server not to read the grant tables in the mysql system schema, and thus to start without using the privilege system at all. This gives anyone with access to the server unrestricted access to all databases.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_name_resolve

> Whether to resolve host names when checking client connections. If this variable is OFF, mysqld resolves host names when checking client connections. If it is ON, mysqld uses only IP numbers; in this case, all Host column values in the grant tables must be IP addresses.

In both cases, I have included only an excerpt from the documentation. Follow the links I gave to read more.